# Touchpad issue on ubuntu 20.10

Tags: dell, touchpad, 20.10

On windows i could use 3 fingers on my touchpad but on ubuntu i cant, only 2 and 1 fingers.
I am using a DELL latitude E5530 and on windows i had DELL touchpad drivers; is it an ubuntu issue or do i need specific touchpad drivers?
I am using ubuntu 20.10 alongside windows.

Greetings, KYNUX